# How to redirect from one html page to another on button click in javascript?

Tags: html

I have two **html** pages `page_1.html` and `page_2.html`. In `page_1.html`, I have a button, which upon being clicked should redirect to `page_2.html`. But it should redirect only when the button has a **charteuse** background color.

So, in `page_1.html`, I have a button:

```
Organization:<div id="org"><input type="checkbox" id="cb1" >ID no: <input type="number" id="org_number" style="visibility: hidden"><br><br>
                     <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" >Mobile No: <input type="tel" id="ph_number" style="visibility: hidden" required></div><br><br>
<button id="button" onmouseover="hovar()" onclick="submit()" >Register</button>
    <script src="back_end.js" async></script>
```

My javascript *(back_end.js)*:

```
    function hovar(){

    var phone=document.getElementById("ph_number").value;
    var btn=document.getElementById("button");

    if (phone.length!=10){
        btn.style.backgroundColor="lightsalmon"
    }
    else{
        btn.style.backgroundColor="chartreuse" 
        btn.style.color="black"
    }
}

function submit(){

    var btn=document.getElementById("button");

    if (getComputedStyle(btn).backgroundColor == "charteuse"){
        window.location.href="page_2.html";
    }
}
```

But, it doesn't redirect to `page_2.html`. What am I missing here? I have also tried `window.location.replace("page_2.html")`, but it's the same.

**EDIT:** I have changed the code a little, it's from a project I'm doing. I have also tried `getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("button")).backgroundColor`, but it doesn't work.

Another thing that I've noticed, is that when I use:

```
if (btn.style.backgroundColor == "charteuse"){
        //console.log(true)
        location.href="page_2.html";
    }
```

it prints `true` into the console but still doesn't redirect to `page_2.html`.

But if I use:

```
if (getComputedStyle(btn).backgroundColor == "charteuse"){
            //console.log(true)
            window.location.href="page_2.html";
        }
```

it doesn't print `true` into the console.
But nevertheless, in both the cases, it doesn't redirect to `page_2.html`

Comment: You have a JS function called `onsubmit`, but you are calling `submit()` instead on your  `HTML` button.

Comment: Did you notice that in the CSS/Javascript code you have `backgoundColor` instead of `backgroundColor`?

Comment: You have to change backgoundcolor to background-color.

Comment: backgroundColor is correkt in js. See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundcolor.asp

Comment: I mean that in your code, you wrote that backgoundColor. You skipped "r"!

Comment: Oh. I apologise. Nice catch. But it should not work even after the typo is fixed. Because it only catches inline css

Comment: I posted another answer.

Comment: Sorry about that typo before I've updated the code. Please have a look.

Comment: (getComputedStyle(btn).backgroundColor returns rgb value. so you should compare with rgb value not string. I posted another answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you should compare like this

```
var btn=document.getElementById("button");
 


  if (getComputedStyle(btn).backgroundColor == "rgb(127, 255, 0)"){
      window.location.href="page_2.html";
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried printing the color name i.e., `alert(document.getElementById("button").style.backgroundColor)` and it prints `charteuse`. So why can't I compare it with the string `charteuse`, and not the rgb value? Plus why use `getComputedStyle` as I have not used any button style in my `css` stylesheet.

Comment: I think you can find answers from here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getcomputedstyle.asp

Answer (score 1):

The `styles` property doesn't directly reflect your CSS, so running

```
if(document.getElementById("button").style.backgoundColor=="red"){
```

never works.

What you can do is change the color to red using javascript:

```js
function changeButtonColor(color) {
    document.getElementById("button").style.backgoundColor = color;
}

changeButtonColor('red');
```

So you do this, wherever you need to change the background color, your if statement will work correctly and you can switch.

Answer (score 1):

### ElementCSSInlineStyle.style

> The style property is used to get as well as set the inline style of
> an element. When getting, it returns a CSSStyleDeclaration object that
> contains a list of all styles properties for that element with values
> assigned for the attributes that are defined in the element's inline
> style attribute.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style

So your if-conditon `document.getElementById("button").style.backgoundColor == "red"` does never return true because the color is defined in your `css-file` and not as an inline argument.

A solution would be using `getComputedStyle(element)` which returns the actuall style from the `css-file`.

```
getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("button")).backgroundColor == "red"
```

as explained here https://zellwk.com/blog/css-values-in-js/

Also in your `css`, you can remove the quotationmarks around `"red"` as mentioned by @George